# Esperar a finalizar tarea Asíncrona de Firebase para mostrar/ocultar item en Menu

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, menú

Estoy empezando a trabajar con Firebase y con sus tareas asíncronas.

Tengo un `LoginActivity` que crea un usuario en la base de datos y por default le da unos priovilegios de acceso "admin" false.

Una vez logueado el usuario, pasamos a la `MainActivity` que dispone de un menú. Realizo una llamada a la base de datos para comprobar si el usuario dispone de derechos admin y si es asi, quiero mostrar en el menu el item para poder acceder a la `AdminActivity` del usuario, si no tiene derechos admin el usuario, se oculta el item del menu y no se puede acceder.

El problema que tengo esque el método `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` se ejecuta como taréa asíncrona y me devuelve el valor `true` o `false` de derechos de admin después de que el menu ya se ha creado y por tanto siempre esta oculto el item de admin del menu.

```
private static boolean adminCheck = false ;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    // If the user has the value admin=false, hide the "Admin" menu item.
    if (!checkAdminRights()) {
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_enter_admin_menu);
        menuItem.setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_enter_admin_menu:
            Intent intentAdmin = new Intent(this, AdminActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentAdmin);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private boolean checkAdminRights() {

    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            adminCheck = dataSnapshot.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("admin").getValue(Boolean.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });

   return adminCheck;

}
}
```

**¿Como podría solucionar el ocultar/ mostrar el item del menu una vez que tengo la información de la base de datos?**

Comment: Podrias dentro de `onCreateOptionsMenu` colocar el metodo de firebase, y en éste, en `onDataChange` hacer que se muestre el menú

Answer (score -1):

1) Recuperar el valor admin antes de cambiar de activity y enviarlo comoun extra en el intent.

2) No construir el menú hasta que se recupere el valor de Firebase.

3) Adjuntar un listener al nodo que tiene la información de admin e invalidar el menú ( lo fuerza a repintarse) después de cada actualización del valor.

Dependerá mucho del flujo de la app.